# how to detect the plugin folder as a np plugin of Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, plugins, windows-vista, mozilla

Here is a question and background: I wanna use some external resources which distributed with XPI file in "plugins" folder. How can I detect where the folder is and load all these resources? I am in Vista and expect the solution works cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

Which "plugins" folder? I have Firefox, Chrome, Chromium-dev, and Safari installs. All of which potentially have their own plugins folders.

On windows, using some very non-x-platform APIs, you can interrogate the registry to find out where the apps are, as well as determine where they have placed their plugin cache folders.

Oh - and certain plugins - Adobe's Flash play for example - install completely outside the 'browsers' plugin folder and simply register their [location in the registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins/The_First_Install_Problem).